# Scrapy: iterate through href elements with list exprehension

Tags: python, list, scrapy

I am currently working in crawling pages from [this site](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/dostojew/idiot/). Now I started with [the first chapter page](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/dostojew/idiot/chap001.html) and looped through the text in the chapter pages, using scrapy. My code did function and the result is almost satisfying. The only problem is that in the csv file the first element in every line is "chapter001.html". Then I tried looping through the pages by selecting the href links one by another.

My code after trying to change the first element of a line by iterating through the urls in the chapter pages:

```
import scrapy

class Litspider2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "litspider2"
    allowed_domains = ["www.projekt-gutenberg.org"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/dostojew/idiot/chap001.html"]

    def parse(self, response):


        yield {"url" : response.css("a[href^=chap]::attr(href)").getall()[x for x in range(0,50)],
                "text" : response.css("div.navi-gb p::text").getall()}
            
        next_chapter = response.css("a[href^=chap]::attr(href)").getall()[-1]

        if next_chapter is not None:
            next_chapter_url = "https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/dostojew/idiot/" + next_chapter
            yield response.follow(next_chapter, callback=self.parse)
```

The only difference with the code before, which reflects the csv result below, was

```
"url" : response.css("a[href^=chap]::attr(href)").getall()[0]
```

which is why it always took the first element in every occasion.

csv result:

```
chap001.html,"Es war gegen Ende des November, bei Tauwetter, als sich um neun Uhr morgens...
chap001.html,"Der General Iwan Fjodorowitsch Jepantschin stand mitten in seinem Arbeitszimmer...
```

How it should look like:

```
chap001.html,"Es war gegen Ende des November, bei Tauwetter, als sich um neun Uhr morgens...
chap002.html,"Der General Iwan Fjodorowitsch Jepantschin stand mitten in seinem Arbeitszimmer...
...
chap050.html,....
```

I tried using list comprehension, but it did not work.

I also tried: response.css("a[href^=chap]::attr(href)").getall()[[x for x in range(0,50)]], but I got an error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list.

I am totally new to scrapy and generally not good in programming, so would be nice if you could help me. Regards.

Comment: I think your approach to apply list slicing with getall() is wrong. i think you should get all images first then slice it.
here is how
links = response.css("a[href^=chap]::attr(href)").getall()

selected_links = links[:50]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting chapter001 as the start of each line is because of the selector you are using for the url.

Your current selector is:

```
"url" : response.css("a[href^=chap]::attr(href)").getall()
```

Which grabs every `<a>` element href that starts with `'chap'`.  The problem with this selector is that on every single page of the site there is a dropdown that lists the links for every single chapter.  So no matter what page you are on you are always going to get a list of every single chapter url as the result of the particular css selector.

A much simpler and highly recommended alternative, if you are simply trying to get the url for the current page is to use `response.url`.

For example:

```
yield {"url" : response.url,
       "text" : response.css("div.navi-gb p::text").getall()}
```

You can use the `urlsplit` function from the built in urllib module if you only want the base of the url.

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know about response.url and the urlsplit before!